# "Car amortization" — word request

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, terminology

If you use your private car for a business trip, usually the company pays the fuel, and also gives you extra money for car maintenance etc. — I'm not sure how is this extra money called in English.

In Czech we use the word "amortization", but is it used in English as well, or is some other word preferred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the company pays you back for money that you spent out of pocket, it's called a *reimbursement*.

If the company agrees to regularly give you a certain amount of money to roughly cover your expenses, but not exactly correlated to the exact amount that you actually spent, it's called an *allowance*.

*Amortization* is not the right word. It means to plan to spread out a large initial cost into many small payments, as in a loan.

Comment: Well, the word _amortization_ smelled wrong to me, that why I asked. It seems that _allowance_ is the choice here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I go on a work trip for two days and travel using my personal car, I am paid *mileage.*   It is calculated by multiplying the miles I traveled by a fixed amount, and is meant to cover fuel costs, insurance costs, maintenance costs and *depreciation* - the reduction in value due to wear and tear on my car.

I also am paid a *per diem* to cover meals, and I can get *reimbursement* for  my lodging if I submit exact receipts.   (U.S.)

Comment: This is helpful also, thanks! (It seems that the UK and the US can't agree once more on vocabulary `:-)` )